# Create an applescript subroutine in a try block

Tags: macos, applescript, try-catch

I am trying to create a subroutine in an Applescript. However, I get a syntax error saying "expected 'error' but found identifier". I believe its because Im doing this inside of a try block. Is there a way around this?

```
try

    on prompt()
    -- Do Something
    end prompt

on error errTxt number errNum -- errTxt and errNum are returned from system
display dialog errTxt & return & errNum
```

Comment: It is not legal to define a subroutine inside a try...on error...end block. That's why it does not compile in Script Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Your "try" block must be within the function, or around the code that calls the function.

**Within the function:**

```
on prompt()
  try
    #do something
  on error errMsg number errNum
    #do something with the error
  end try
end prompt()
```

**Around the function call:**

```
try
  my prompt()
on error errMsg number errNum
  #do something with the error
end try
```

Both options will catch any errors generated within the function. The second option has the added feature that, should the function not exist, you will catch that error as well.